# When I try to log into my firebase account, I get an error. The error is here but I can't find it

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication

```
class FirestoreClass {
fun getUserDetails(activity: Activity){
    mFirestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(getCurrentUserID())
        .get()
  52      .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName, document.toString())

  55          val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!

            when(activity){
                is LoginActivity->{
                    activity.userLoggedInSuccess(user)
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e->
            when(activity){
                is LoginActivity ->{
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }

            }
            Log.e(
                activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Error while getting user details.",e
            )
        }
 }
}
LoginActivity ->
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {
 private fun logInRegisteredUser(){
        if (validateLoginDetails()) {
            showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

            val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString().trim { it <= ' '}
            val password = binding.etPassword.text.toString().trim { it <= ' '}

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->


                    if (task.isSuccessful){
                        FirestoreClass().getUserDetails(this@LoginActivity)
                    }else{
                        hideProgressDialog()
                        showErrorSnackbar(task.exception!!.message.toString(),true)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xikmat.osonjob.firestore.FirestoreClass$getUserDetails$1.invoke(FirestoreClass.kt:55)
at com.xikmat.osonjob.firestore.FirestoreClass$getUserDetails$1.invoke(FirestoreClass.kt:52)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line `52` you marked with `!!` that what method `document.toObject(User::class.java)` returns will definitely not be null,
but for some reason it is null - hence your error.
The steps you need to take are:

1. Find out why the content of the document is unreachable
   (According to the API documentation for `toObject()`, it will return `null` if the document doesn't exist. You can first check to see if it exists using `exists()`)
   Is `getCurrentUserID()` method implemented by you? Maybe it has a bug?
2. Handle situations when it is null, e.g:

```
val user = document.toObject(User::class.java) 
if (user == null) {
   activity.hideProgressDialog()
   return@addOnSuccessListener
}
if (activity is LoginActivity){
   activity.userLoggedInSuccess(user)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me a lot. As you suggested, user returns null. I did everything according to the video tutorial and reviewed it several times and did not find any errors in getCurrentUser. Could you help me to find what is wrong

Comment: fun getCurrentUserID(): String {
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        var currentUserID = ""
        if (currentUser != null){
            currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }
        return currentUserID
    }

Answer (score 0):

you should not use **!!** in kotlin. replace it with check null normal

```
document?.let{ doc ->
    val user = doc.toObject(User::class.java)
    //do something here
    if(activity is LoginActivity){
        activity.userLoggedInSuccess(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me a lot. As you suggested, user returns null. I did everything according to the video tutorial and reviewed it several times and did not find any errors in getCurrentUser. Could you help me to find what is wrong – 
Sattarov
 Apr 21 at 15:19   
fun getCurrentUserID(): String { val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser var currentUserID = "" if (currentUser != null){ currentUserID = currentUser.uid } return currentUserID }